# Postgresql: Aggregate results by patterns

Tags: postgresql

I need to list how many cars I have on different pools.

Here is what I get:

```
select count(*), pool from cars group by 2 order by 1 desc;

 count | pool
-------+--------
    71 | A-12-A
    69 | B-45-A
    19 | A-45-B
    18 | A-69-A
    15 | B-12-B
    13 | A-67-B
(6 rows)
```

But I don't really care avout the middle value. I'm only interessted in the first and the last letter (the car classification and an internal value we use).

If it is even possible, how can I get something like this:

```
 count | pool
-------+--------
    89 | A-%-A
    69 | B-%-A
    32 | A-%-B
    15 | B-%-B
(6 rows)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select count(*) as cnt, 
       regexp_replace(pool, '-[0-9]{2}-', '-%-', 'gi') as clean_pool
from cars
group by clean_pool
order by 1 desc;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ac449/2

This assumes that the middle part always contains two digits. If this is not the case, you need to adjust the regex to cope with that.